# Scanning Rest API's through OWASP zap inside a docker environment

Tags: docker, owasp, zap

I set an Azure devops CI/CD build that will start a vm where Owasp Zap is running as a proxy and where the Owasp zap Azure devops task will run on a target url and copy my report in an Azure Storage.

Followed this guy's beautiful tutorial:  https://kasunkodagoda.com/2017/09/03/introducing-owasp-zed-attack-proxy-task-for-visual-studio-team-services/ 
*(also the guy who created the Azure devops task)*

All well and good but recently I wanted to use an REST Api as a target url.  The Owasp zap task in azure devops doesn't have the ability. Even asked the creator (https://github.com/kasunkv/owasp-zap-vsts-task/issues/30#issuecomment-452258621) and he also didn't think this is available through the Azure devops task and only through docker.

On my next quest I am now trying to get it running inside a docker image. (Firstly inside Azure devops but that wasn't smooth https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/5176 )
And finally getting on this tutorial (https://zaproxy.blogspot.com/2017/06/scanning-apis-with-zap.html)

Where I am trying to run a docker image with the following steps:

---  `docker pull owasp/zap2docker-weekly`

--running the container

-------command : `docker run -v ${pwd}:/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t https://apiurl/api.json -f openapi -z "-configfile /zap/wrk/options.prop`"

```
------- options.prop file
  -config replacer.full_list\(0\).description=auth1 \
  -config replacer.full_list\(0\).enabled=true \
  -config replacer.full_list\(0\).matchtype=REQ_HEADER \
  -config replacer.full_list\(0\).matchstr=Authorization \
  -config replacer.full_list\(0\).regex=false \
  -config replacer.full_list\(0\).replacement=Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

But This scans only the root url not every URL. As I am typing this question i tried to download the json file from the root and running the docker run command with passing the json file with the -t I am getting number of imported url's : what seems to be everything. But this seems to freeze inside powershell.

Which step do i miss to get a full recursive scan on my rest api ?
Any one some ideas or some help pls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your property file format is wrong. You only need the '-config' and '\'s if you set the options directly on the command line. In the property file you should have:

```
replacer.full_list(0).description=auth1
replacer.full_list(0).enabled=true
replacer.full_list(0).matchtype=REQ_HEADER
replacer.full_list(0).matchstr=Authorization
replacer.full_list(0).regex=false
replacer.full_list(0).replacement=Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Secondly, what does https://apiurl/api.json return and have you checked you can access it from within your docker container?
Try running

```
curl https://apiurl/api.json
```

and see what you get.

Comment: That was it. the config file had the wrong formatting , Tnx !!